# one/two each of + plural nouns

Tags: grammar, phrases, determiners

I'd like to know an alternative phrasing of structures like "I want **one each of** tomatoes, bananas, apricots and pears.

Secondly, what syntactic role does "each" play in this phrase?

Comment: Well, _`N` each_ is a complex quantifier idiom, to start with. And it's short for _one of each_; the _of_ tends to get deleted when there is a following _of_ to delimit the range of the quantifier. It is somewhat confusing to mix plural range nouns with a singular quantifier, though; this would work lots better with _I want **three** each of tomatoes and pears._ Note that there are other formulations: _I want one each for the bridesmaids, and two for the bride_ can determine who gets it instead of what it is.

Comment: @JohnLawler in what other structures does the first "of" tend to be deleted too?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to avoid the *each of* idiom, you could simply say:

> I want ***one tomato*** and ***one pear***.

You could probably also get away with:

> I want ***one tomato and pear***.

That, however, is somewhat unclear (is it a tomato/pear combination?  is "tomato and pear" an adjective for an unspecified noun, such as a *tomato and pear burrito*?); If what you're really looking for is one of each, I would specify such with *one tomato and one pear*.

Update:  If you are looking for a longer list, you can certainly use:

> I want *one tomato*, *one banana*, *one apricot*, and *one pear*.

but that gets rather unwieldy fairly quickly.  Hence the shortcut of ***one each of***.

Thanks to Jason Bassford for pointing out that you can also say:

> I want **a** tomato, banana, apricot, and pear.

and this is not as unclear as I originally thought.  (Sometimes, when you think about something too much, you can confuse yourself.  At least I can.)

Comment: I've edited the question to show my interest in a longer chain of different fruits; what's the alternative phrasing then?

Comment: @GJC -- I've updated my answer.  You can add as many options as you like, but more than two or so and you're better off with the **_n_ each of** shortcut.

Comment: Unless you're using the words adjectivally, there's no reason to not elide all but the first quantifier. If you simply say *I'd like a tomato, pear, and banana* (and nothing else), I don't see how that can be confused with something involving a combination. (Assuming context doesn't play a role either.)